# How to pass Linq / Lambda Expressions as parameter in WCF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have a variety of search operations, if there was a way to pass Lambda Expressions as parameter

```
[OperationContract]
ICollection<Person> GetPeoplePage(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);
```

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: you can't - there is no way to serialize code automatically.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem on this link http://expressiontree.codeplex.com/